# jdbc pyspark write takes too long and fails with GC error on databricks

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, databricks

I have the following code :

```
output.write.option("numPartitions","1").jdbc(url = sql_db_url, table = "dbo.test", mode = "append", properties = sql_db_configs)
```

it is pyspark running in databricks but outlet dataframe performs heavy aggregations and hence the jdbc write action takes too long

the data is small in size

any idea how to optimize the jdbc write for pyspark in databricks because I get the following error after a long execution time :
Driver is up but is not responsive, likely due to GC.

Comment: Can you try by removing .option("numPartitions","1")

Comment: already tested this , and tested several partitions number too